# Userdefaults Boolean for button

Tags: swift, xcode, nsuserdefaults

I am fairly new to Swift programming. Using Userdefaults I was trying to customize user behaviour. Below image is of my initial controller. I require to save userdefaults so that App remembers the user selection of button, (i.e. A or B). Can you assist to provide me a function that I use in viewDidLoad and it remembers the button selection and segues to its respective ViewController.[image]

My code to perfrom segue if Button A or B is selected is

```
let parent = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DashboardVC") as! DashboardVC
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(parent!, animated: true)
```

Yet it doesnt segue. It keeps loading my initial viewcontroller.

Answer (score 2):

do like

set the **tag** for each button and create the common method for handle the function , for e.g

```
@IBAction func handle_Action(_ sender: UIButton) {
      defaultName.set(sender.tag, forKey: "yourKeyName")
 }
```

and in your class

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController {
  let defaultName = UserDefaults.standard

// finally access the integer in your Viewload

      override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

     let getVal =  defaultName.integer(forKey: "yourKeyName") as Int
        if getVal == 1{ //called by A
        }else   if getVal == 2{
            //called by B
        }else{ // not interactwithButton action      }
    }
```

Comment: if you wanna additional info i will add another example also

Comment: Thanks for your response. Im getting a "initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'int'" for your if let statement. Suggestion?

Comment: Thanks for the updated Answer. I added an Edit to my Question. I understand my new query is out of scope to my initial Question. But, i fail to understand why its not segueing to on viewDidLoad. Can you see why?

Comment: @Roger - sorry for delay reply, for your last comment answer : didLoad has purely memory management functions, you can use it as (part of a) constructor. What may work, is to start a segue in viewDidAppear, however I would suggest to start with the view you want at the first time.